# Docker run results in error: layer does not exist

Tags: docker

I'm trying to setup redmine (with postgres) on my raspberry pi 3 using docker-compose. It already worked once, but then I tried to install plugins and somehow managed to bork my system.

Now it won't let me start my database container anymore. Even creating a new `postgres:12.8` container, yields the error `layer does not exist`:

```
$ docker run --rm -it postgres:12.8 bash
docker: Error response from daemon: layer does not exist.
```

I've already restarted the system twice, which sadly didn't change anything.
How can I get this to work again?

Additional info:

```
$ docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 5
  Running: 4
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 65
 Server Version: 19.03.13
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.19.66-v7+
 Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: armv7l
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 926.1MiB
 Name: raspberrypi
 ID: <redacted>
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
```

---

Update 1:

Removing the image (via `docker rmi`) doesn't stop the error.

```
$ docker run --rm -it postgres:12.8 bash
Unable to find image 'postgres:12.8' locally
12.8: Pulling from library/postgres
Digest: sha256:e10cd754296c1b3e93a121bcc64550d183df56f20bab47e08cacb123fb969b5e
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:12.8
docker: Error response from daemon: layer does not exist.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Other images can be run as usual:

```
$ docker run --rm -it alpine bash
Unable to find image 'alpine:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
4ee0caa23b36: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:eb3e4e175ba6d212ba1d6e04fc0782916c08e1c9d7b45892e9796141b1d379ae
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
/ # whoami
root
/ #
```

Answer (score 15):

Nuking `/var/lib/docker` seems to get the system working again - this removes all images and lots of other docker-related data.

This doesn't feel like a great solution, but it'll have to do for now.

```
$ sudo service docker stop
$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
$ sudo service docker start
$ docker run --rm -it postgres:12.8 bash
Unable to find image 'postgres:12.8' locally
12.8: Pulling from library/postgres
607f77084e8a: Pull complete
ce89a6184ac9: Pull complete
2a4e6e7ac863: Pull complete
f3b6f439172b: Pull complete
2e803a3461b4: Pull complete
467430f26cab: Pull complete
1a81afc37621: Pull complete
4ceea61b7b5c: Pull complete
1f5bfa96a004: Pull complete
b40859b8e537: Pull complete
c7b3bf3cab26: Pull complete
653c63793cd5: Pull complete
aad7328542d8: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:e10cd754296c1b3e93a121bcc64550d183df56f20bab47e08cacb123fb969b5e
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:12.8
root@8ba418515688:/#
```

References:

- https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/1808
- https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/1313

Comment: The "less nuclear" option of restarting docker as in AP22's answer should be preferrable.

Answer (score 11):

I have the error below and a restart of docker daemon seems to fix it. Still wondering what causes it in the first place.

> level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.41/containers/create returned error: layer does not exist"

To restart docker daemon run:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm late to the party but perhaps my answer could help someone in future. So here is the issue I faced:

- Suddenly a few (3) of my containers including portainer stopped working. On running the containers again using docker container run resulted in layer not found error.
- Container listing using docker container ls -a did not list the stopped containers
- Image listing using docker image ls did not list the three images associated with the three stopped containers.
- Trying to pull the new image doesn't work

```
latest: Pulling from portainer/portainer-ce
Digest: sha256:9fa1ec78b4e29d83593cf9720674b72829c9cdc0db7083a962bc30e64e27f64e
Status: Image is up to date for portainer/portainer-ce:latest
```

- Trying to remove images using docker image rm  resulted in the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: unrecognized image ID sha256:a87d51c7a32408ba63e65888d023ad7d4328fd575d8a4c8bd8cffa495fcd055c
```

**The Solution**

1. Note down the sha256 id during the image removal process as listed above, in my case for portainer the sha256 id of the image was *a87d51c7a32408ba63e65888d023ad7d4328fd575d8a4c8bd8cffa495fcd055c*
2. Navigate to /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256 and delete/move the file with the exact name as the sha256 ID.
3. Try pulling the image again using the docker image pull command. It should work now.
4. Run the container/compose file.
5. Repeat the process for all offending images.

This is a slightly tedious process, especially for a lot of images but it is better than nuking the /var/lib/docker directory

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution to Ken Anderson's above if it works for you:
For me, it happened on redis:alpine.
and `docker run -it redis:alpine` ended in "layer not found" too.

```
$ docker run -it redis:alpine
docker: Error response from daemon: layer does not exist.
```

I had no container and no image showing:

`docker container ls -a|grep redis` returned nothing

`docker images | grep redis`  returned nothing

Just manually re-pulling the image (`docker pull redis:alpine`) worked for me.

```
$ docker pull redis:alpine
alpine: Pulling from library/redis
c41833b44d91: Pull complete
e3a3ca428482: Pull complete
a43e117b1823: Pull complete
fc0c5fc7bd09: Pull complete
c76199591618: Pull complete
999bf2ab518f: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:221f7fa5b4c563971358755893263d64b0b52e9798f6320f2898be499fb3b6b6
Status: Downloaded newer image for redis:alpine
docker.io/library/redis:alpine

$ docker run -it redis:alpine
1:C 01 Apr 2023 09:17:21.850 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1:C 01 Apr 2023 09:17:21.850 # Redis version=7.0.10, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
1:C 01 Apr 2023 09:17:21.850 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
1:M 01 Apr 2023 09:17:21.852 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
...
```

Comment: It probably worked because you pulled a newer image that doesn't use the missing layers (and re-pulling won't work in other cases)